# Change language of MessageUI forms and ActionSheet

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, messageui, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm currently using the `MessageUI` framework for sending SMS and Emails, but my app is in Spanish, while the `MessageUI` interface is in english, how can I change the button texts of the `MessageUI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your project is in spanish? 
This weekend I had this problem and it was because I had the project in english. I added spanish to the project and removed english and messageui, and other system interfaces appeared in spanish.

You may need to do a clean or even delete te app fron the device and reinstall.

To add spanish click on your project, go to localizations and click the + button and add spanish. then click on english and the - button to remove it

[image]

Comment: Project navigator, click on your project (blue icon) and you get the screen with the project and targets, click on the project

Comment: Found it, but when adding the new localization it shows me countries, and no latin american ones nor spanish options, not even USA shows up actually. I added the new localization with Spanish in the text, entered by myself, and it still shows up in english.

Comment: Did you find where I said? Where I say I can only choose languages, not countries... In the .plist you can choose countries, but that is not the place

Comment: Yeah, just saw the mistake, that did the trick, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You don't modify the buttons of the `MessageUI` interface, as normally its interface is automatically translated in the language of the user (the language set in the settings of the iPhone).

If this is not the case during your tests, this can come from multiple reasons:

- If your try on the simulator and not on the device, I guess that simulator versions of the frameworks are lightweight versions that does not have every translated strings (whereas of course on the device all localisations are defined). Maybe try on your real device instead
- If iOS can't find a translation for a given string for the current locale of the phone, it fallback to use the locale defined by the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` Info.plist key. Thus if the translation for your buttons are not found in spanish, it will use the english translation if your CFBundleDevelopmentRegion is set to 'en'. *This explains the behavior of the previous point: on the simulator the translation does probably not exist in the framework for spanish (but should exist on the device), so it falls back to english.*

Comment: The phone is set to spanish, and it still shows up in english.

Comment: Did you also add "Spanish (es)" to your project's Localizations (select your project, go to the Info tab and use the "+" button to add the "Spanish (es)" localization to your project)

Comment: Thanks for the help, your answer although very informative, was a little les helpful than the other one, so I'm accepting his. Thanks again, though.